# How to create a searchable database with a single-field search box at the front end?

Tags: custom-field, database

I have seen many websites having developed a (hidden) database of their certified clients (actually details of the clients and the given certificates) and they have devoted a web page where clients can search for and retrieve and view their data by simply entering their "certificate number".

Does anyone know how I can make the same thing for my website? As I understand, there should be a customized search.php as well as a customized searchpage.php to tackle this, but I have no coding knowledge and would appreciate it if experts would be kind enough to guide me through the steps so I can copy-paste the stuff and make this thing happen!

I have already searched through the Wordpress Plugins and the only plugin that seemed to be able to do this for me was " Participants Database", but even though I studied and followed all the guidelines the author had provided (even more detailed at his own website), I could not figure out how to get it to work for me as desired!_or maybe I found it complicated for my level! (so if anyone can help with the plugin, that would be great as well).

Anyways, here's all what I need:

1- On the back end, I need to create a database to register (and update) certified clients data with custom fields as under:

Certificate No:
Client Name:
Country:
City:
Certificate Title:
Certificate Type:
Issue Date:
Membership Status:

(Question: Do I have to make a separate post for each client?)

2- On the front end, I need to have a search box with only one field (i.e. certificate number) to put on a page that I want to devote to "Certified Clients". On this page, each client would be able to see their registered data (i.e. those 8 fields already saved in the database) in the result page ONLY AFTER they have submitted their certificate number in the search box.

So, this way, only certain data will be retrieved from the database and each client would be able to see their respective data and not all data (i.e. those from other clients).

It seems so simple (as I can see numerous website are having and taking advantage of such searchable database) and yet so complicated for me! Of course my question could be the question of many other novice people like me who're in need of the same support!

So, I would appreciate any help with that from you nice and surely knowledgeable guys out there :)

Cheers!

Comment: Is your certificate a Custom Post Type or is this in a separate table?

Comment: Well, that's also something I was wondering about. The certificate details need to be saved in the database in a way but which do you think is better in my case? And if you would recommend having the data in a table, then how and where can I create it and how to get it hidden on the website (i.e. to be only viewable for me at the back end for edits and updates)?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Guess what! I just found what I was looking for and I'd like to share it with you.
There is this newly-developed plugin that meets my needs (as described in my first post) and is fully customizable for other purposes as well. So, if you were also looking for such a solution, look no more! I hope many others would install and use the plugin and rate it high as an appreciation to the author/developer of such a great plugin. ***Here's the link:***

https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-searchable-data-entry-system/

I think I can now mark the question I'd raised as **[resolved]** !

Happy using it:)

Cheers!

Comment: It's look like a bad advertising or a way to spam your plugin...